# Error on opening any Kettle Transformation file in Pentaho Data Integration

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have been working with PDI since a long time and while opening the same file which used to work perfectly before is now showing the below error immediately after opening:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.TransFileListener.open(TransFileListener.java:112)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile(Spoon.java:4623)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$2.drop(Spoon.java:976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

The same file opens in other machine perfectly and wors perfectly. In Spoon debug log, I get the below error:

```
Unable to update instance pid: null
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.Exception: Unable to lock bundle cache: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to lock bundle cache: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:176)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:648)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:232)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot$4.run(KarafBoot.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot.startup(KarafBoot.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.osgi.registryExtension.OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.init(OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.java:105)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.init(PluginRegistry.java:558)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironment.java:101)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:74)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:617)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
17:30:45,214 ERROR [KarafBoot] Error starting Karaf
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:653)
    at org.apache.karaf.main.Main.launch(Main.java:232)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot$4.run(KarafBoot.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.pentaho.platform.osgi.KarafBoot.startup(KarafBoot.java:247)
    at org.pentaho.di.osgi.registryExtension.OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.init(OSGIPluginRegistryExtension.java:105)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.plugins.PluginRegistry.init(PluginRegistry.java:558)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleClientEnvironment.init(KettleClientEnvironment.java:101)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:96)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.init(KettleEnvironment.java:74)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:617)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$1.call(Spoon.java:609)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to lock bundle cache: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:176)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:648)
    ... 15 more
17:32:39,344 ERROR [KarafLifecycleListener] The Kettle Karaf Lifecycle Listener failed to execute properly after waiting for 100 seconds. Releasing lifecycle hold, but some services may be unavailable.
2019/12/17 17:32:47 - Spoon - Logging is at level : Debug
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : There was an error while reading the shared objects (continuing load) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Unexpected problem reading shared objects from XML file : null
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Error reading information from input stream
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Unexpected problem reading shared objects from XML file : null
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Error reading information from input stream
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.shared.SharedObjects.<init>(SharedObjects.java:186)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.readSharedObjects(TransMeta.java:3420)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta.loadXML(TransMeta.java:2935)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.TransFileListener.open(TransFileListener.java:61)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.openFile(Spoon.java:4623)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$2.drop(Spoon.java:976)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DNDListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget.Drop_64(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.dnd.DropTarget$3.method6(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.ole.win32.COMObject.callback6(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1359)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7990)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9290)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:685)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException: 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Error reading information from input stream
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - 
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:635)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:559)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:540)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.shared.SharedObjects.<init>(SharedObjects.java:112)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     ... 28 more
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General - Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     at org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler.loadXMLFile(XMLHandler.java:612)
2019/12/17 17:34:25 - General -     ... 31 more
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
2019/12/17 17:34:26 - Spoon - ERROR (version 7.0.0.0-25, build 1 from 2016-11-05 15.35.36 by buildguy) : An unexpected error occurred in Spoon:  
2019/12/17 17:34:26 - Spoon - null
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling PDI but it did not work. Also tried clearing the cache in pentaho_data_integration_dir\data-integration\system\karaf\caches.

**Edit:** This error also appears while saving a newly created transformation/job in Pentaho Data Integration.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ahh.. its difficult to check but if i was at your place would check the below

1. all required components are available in spoon instance in which you are opening the file.
2. right click and compare the file in xml version to spot the difference.
3. check the java_home settings and pentaho service is running or not.
4. remove and replace it with back up file.
5. place the file in a different folder and then try to open it. you may get a more descriptive error to action accordingly.

Comment: can you please elaborate on the 1st and 3rd point? I have checked rest all the points already but didn't find the root cause

Comment: For Point 1. at the below location check if the required components used in your job or transformation file is available C:\Pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\plugins. you can also validate when you go to design pane in spoon instance and you see relevant components or steps are available for use. for Point 3. refer below link to see java_home is configured correctly https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.2/0F0/0G0/020